# Pass structure array to function using pointers

Tags: c, function, struct, pass-by-reference

I am trying to send a structure array as reference, but for some reason I cannot get it to work, as value it is able to pass it but not as reference (&)

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct mystruct {
    char line[10];
};

void func(struct mystruct record[])
{
    printf ("YES, there is a record like %s\n", record[0].line);
}

int main()
{
    struct mystruct record[1];
    strcpy(record[0].line,"TEST0");
    func(record);    
    return 0;
}
```

I thought that only by calling the function func(&record) and changing the func function arguments as "struct mystruct *record[]" it was going to work... but it didn't.

Any help please.

Comment: "doesn't work", isn't a very useful description of what problem you are encountering. Please tell us what output you are getting.

Comment: The error is kind of weird when I try the reference this, but this is it:

Comment: C has no pass by reference, everything is pass by value. But `func(record)` is already passing the `record` array as a pointer. That is, it is already by "reference" as you seem to want (it is not copying the entire struct array).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the specific error you're getting. Also, you don't need to put tags in the title. We have tags for that.

Comment: Read about arrays and pointers and implicit conversion. Should be detailed in any good C book. For a starter: don't think like "pass-by-reference", even **iff** you are aware this is not what actually happens. Just think of "pass-by-pointer" (2 letters less, btw.)

Comment: Your code is already correct and passes the record by reference.  (In C, the concept of passing by reference is achieved by passing by pointer, and your code does that). You could change the parameter types but there is no need to do so.

Comment: @M.M: A pointer is a first class object with its own value. A reference has no value on its own.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you've got your pointers and references concepts mixed up.

`func(&record)` would pass the address of the variable record and not a reference.

passing pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct mystruct {
    char line[10];
};

void func(struct mystruct * record)
{
    printf ("YES, there is a record like %s\n", record[0].line);
    // OR
    printf ("YES, there is a record like %s\n", record->line);
}

int main()
{
    struct mystruct record[1];
    strcpy(record[0].line,"TEST0");
    func(record); // or func(&record[0])
    return 0;
}
```

if you must pass a reference, try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct mystruct {
    char line[10];
};

void func(struct mystruct & record)
{
    printf ("YES, there is a record like %s\n", record.line);
}

int main()
{
    struct mystruct record[1];
    strcpy(record[0].line,"TEST0");
    func(record[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Update

To address the comment(s) below,

- references are not available in pure C, available only in C++
- the 'fault' in the original code was a `struct mystruct record[]` should have been `struct mystruct & record`

Comment: Oh yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, the first option of the pointer, I mixed up the stuff talking about a reference since those pointers help you simulate kind of the same thing. thanks

Comment: This question is tagged `c`, so there are no references. You only get references in `c++`.

Comment: C does not support references. And you don't point out the fault in the question's code.

Comment: The original code was correct, there was no fault. `struct mystruct record[]` means exactly the same as `struct mystruct * record`  , as a function parameter.